Why does Active Directory Certificate Services require Remote Registry Service?
I'm setting up a two-tier certificate authority using Active Directory Certificate Services. The offline air-gapped root certificate authority was easy to set up and get going. The intermediate certificate authority, however, seems like it wants Remote Registry Service to be active before it will issue certificates.
Why does Remote Registry Service need to be active for this application?
Thanks in advance for your replies :)

It is necessary for AD CS remote administration. CA stores its configuration in registry.

Thanks. Could you possibly go into more detail? I'd like to be sure I fully understand the reasoning behind this before I activate it. Which registry does the information get stored in -- the AD server's registry, or the intermediate CA server's registry?

CA configuration is stored on CA itself.

If the CA configuration gets stored on the CA itself, then why does Remote Registry service need to be active?

Why Remote Registry Service is Required for Intermediate Certificate Authority in AD CS
While the exact reason behind the requirement isn't publicly documented by Microsoft, there are two possible explanations for why AD CS, particularly the intermediate CA, might need Remote Registry Service:

Configuration Management:  AD CS might leverage the Remote Registry Service to read or write specific registry entries during the intermediate CA configuration process. These entries could hold details about certificate templates, signing algorithms, or other crucial settings for issuing certificates.

Security Context: In some scenarios, enabling Remote Registry Service might be necessary for a secure communication channel between components within AD CS. This could be particularly relevant for the intermediate CA which interacts with both the offline root CA and potentially other network resources.


Since a root CA operates in a disconnected environment, it might not require this level of configuration management or secure communication, explaining why it functions without Remote Registry Service.

Consider if there are alternative ways to achieve the intermediate CA's configuration without enabling Remote Registry Service. This might involve manual configuration or leveraging other tools.

Remember, enabling Remote Registry Service does introduce some security risks. If it's absolutely necessary, ensure strong access controls are implemented to minimize potential vulnerabilities.
